# How to make namespace in lua?

Tags: lua

I want to bind static class function to lua.
As you know, static class function is something difference with class function.
So function call code in lua should be like this...

```
//C++
lua_tinker::def(L, "Foo_Func", &Foo::Func);

//Lua
Foo_Func()
```

But I want to call function in lua like this

```
//Lua
Foo.Func()
```

Is there any way to use like that?
Lua table might be helpful. But I cannot find any references.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, that would be done with a table and is in fact how most modules work when you import them with [`require`](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html).

```
Foo = {} -- make a table called 'Foo'
Foo.Func = function() -- create a 'Func' function in stored in the table
    print 'foo' -- do something
end
Foo.Func() -- call the function
```

Comment: Remember that if you declared:

Foo.Func = function(this) ... end

you can call it:

Foo:Func() ( notice the ':' ) , this will pass the Foo table as the first function parameter too.

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll find [PiL chapter 26.2](http://www.lua.org/pil/26.2.html) most interesting.
If you compile your library to the same name as the table (so filename == modulename) then you can simply require() the module.